# Figaro syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting '}' (SyntaxError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables

**Update September 3rd** this is not working either.....

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS'                           # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"]        # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]    # required
  }
  config.fog_directory  = ENV["AWS_S3_BUCKET"]                 # required
end
```

---

I am using the figaro gem to store env variables of my aws credentials.

here is my initializers/carrierwave.rb file

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS'                       # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => ENV[AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID]        # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV[AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY]    # required
    #:region                 => 'us-east-1',                  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
    #:host                   => 's3.example.com',             # optional, defaults to nil
    #:endpoint               => 'https://s3.example.com:8080' # optional, defaults to nil
  }
  config.fog_directory  = ENV[AWS_S3_BUCKET]                 # required
end
```

when I do rails s I am getting this error

```
/initializers/carrierwave.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting '}' (SyntaxError)
    :aws_access_key_id      => ENV...
     ^
/Users/judyngai/tryagain_newproject/onemonth/lintong/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting keyword_end
    :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV[AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY]  ...
```

here is my application.yml as generated by the figaro gem

```
 AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "blahblahblahblah"                   
 AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "blahblahblahblah"
 AWS_S3_BUCKET: "blahblahblahblah"
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put quotes around your key names, and need commas to separate each item (just like any Ruby hash):

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id      => ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
    :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]
  }
  config.fog_directory  = ENV["AWS_S3_BUCKET"]                 # required
end
```